# How to use cordova-plugin-datepicker in ionic app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I don't know how to use cordova-plugin-datepicker https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker in ionic app, I mean which import to add and where, which variable to declare and which object to call. I tried to follow the instructions on github but is not clear.
Thank everyone that responds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the plugin.
2. Go to the related ionic page you want to use the plugin with.
3. Declare the plugin right after the imports like this : `declare const datePicker`
4. Now you can use it in your page. Example usage : `datePicker.show(options, onSuccess, onError);` as described in the plugin home page.

NOTE: If you check any DatePicker.js file in [here](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker/tree/master/www), you will see how it is exported at the end of the file.